# Regular Expression help - string find and replace

Tags: regex

I'm using Komodo and need to find / replace a huge amount of code.

I need to replace all occurrences of the following, but retain a certain portion of it as shown below:

```
<th title="THIS IS THE STRING THAT NEEDS TO BE RETAINED">StartDate</th>
```

replace with::

```
<th><?=$this->Html->image('bm.acp.help.png', array('alt' => 'Help', 'title'=>'THIS IS THE STRING THAT NEEDS TO BE RETAINED'));?>StartDate</th>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e '
$a = qq{<th title="THIS IS THE STRING THAT NEEDS TO BE RETAINED">StartDate</th>};
$a =~ s{<th title=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/th>}{<th><?=$this->Html->image("bm.acp.help.png", array("alt" => "Help", "title"=>"$1"));?>$2<\\th>}; 
print "\n\n$a";'
```